# Vue3 - Suspense not rendering fallback

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, office-js, office-addins

I have below two components (parent and child)

```
.
├── Index.vue (Parent)
└── _GetShipment.vue (Child)
```

In the `Index.vue` I am trying to get the content of the e-mail body using Office.js's getAsync:

```html
<script>
import Shipment from './_GetShipment.vue';
import { ref, defineComponent } from 'vue';


export default defineComponent({
    setup() {
        const shipments = ref([]);

        Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(
            "text",
            function (result) {
                if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                    let matches = result.value.match(/S\w{3}\d{8,9}/ig);
                    if(matches){
                        shipments.value = matches;
                    }
                }
            }
        );

        return {
            shipments,
        }
    },
    components: {
        Shipment,
    },
})
</script>

<template>
     <div>
         <div v-if="shipments.length === 1">
             <Shipment :id="shipments[0]" />
         </div>
     </div>
</template>
```

The above checks the email body content to see if there is a regular expression match. If there is, it will add the match to an array `shipments`.

Currently, if there is only one match found, this will be rendered in the child component called `_GetShipment`:

```html
<script>
import { ref, Suspense } from 'vue';
import route from '../../../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/src/js';

export default {
    props: ['id'],
    async setup(props) {
        const shipment = ref();
        await fetch(route('getShipment', {id : props.id}))
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => shipment.value = data);
        return { shipment };

    }
};
</script>
<template>
      <div>
         Viewing shipment {{ id }}: <br />
         <Suspense>
             <template #fallback>
                 Loading...
             </template>
             <pre>{{ shipment }}</pre>
         </Suspense>
      </div>
</template>
```

Fetching the e-mail body content works fine, and the same goes for getting the details using `fetch()`.

However, the **loading** fallback of `Suspense` is not being triggered. When loading the page, it is simple blank until `fetch` is completed.

Why is the `#fallback` not being rendered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're incorrectly applying the `<Suspense>` in the same component that has `async setup`. The `<Suspense>` needs to be in an *ancestor* (i.e., any component between the root and the component using `async setup`).

The fact that your component renders at all without error implies you already have a `<Suspense>` in an ancestor, so the solution here is to remove the one inside your `async setup` component, or move the `<Suspense>` to a wrapper that renders your fallback.